# Laravel many to many relationship update

Tags: laravel

I have some hard time with many to many relationship when I try to update the pivot columns.
Here is my database 'order_product' table

**order_product_table**
[image]

First, I am trying to update the products of that order.

**Order update form**
[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
@if($products)
 <select class="form-control kt-select2 products" name="products[]" required>
   <option selected disabled>Select a product</option>
     @foreach($products as $product)
       <option value="{{ $product->id }}" data-price="{{ $product->selling_price }}" {{ $product->id === $order_product->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $product->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
@endif
```

My spaghetti code...

```
public function update(Order $order)
{
    $attributes = $this->validateOrder();
    $order->update($attributes);

    $products = \request('products');
    $quantity = \request('quantity');
    $price = \request('price');
    $discount = \request('discount');

    $total = 0;

    if ($products) {
        $order->products()->sync([$order->id => ['product_id' => $products]]);
    }

    $this->flashMessage('success', 'Your order was updated with success!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Try a lot of things, but it does not work ...

Comment: What do you have in `$products` ? just an integer with the ID of the product or is it an array of IDs ?

Comment: How are you recovering the attributes of each product ? is `$quantity` an `array` of integers ?

Comment: I have an array for each things, an array for quantity with quantities for each product, and array of discounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this:

```php
public function update(Order $order)
{
    $attributes = $this->validateOrder();
    $order->update($attributes);

    //should be an array of products ID
    $products = \request('products');
    $quantity = \request('quantity');
    $price = \request('price');
    $discount = \request('discount');

    $total = 0;

    foreach($products as $key => $productId) {

        //normalize attributes
        $attributes = [
            'price' => $price[$key],
            'quantity' => $quantity[$key],
            'discount' => $discount[$key],
        ];

        $order->products()->updateExistingPivot($productId, $attributes);
    }

    $this->flashMessage('success', 'Your order was updated with success!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

For more information about `updateExistingPivot()` method, check [Laravel documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: With your code, it pass the if and show the success message, but it does not update my database record.

Comment: https://ibb.co/chzg7Nt - this is for the products and this is for the attributes - https://ibb.co/TRJSSY2

Answer (score 0):

For the `sync()` method in many to many relation, you need to provide the relation ID as index of the array.

```
$syncable = [];
foreach ($products as $key => $productId) {
    $syncable[$productId] = [
        'price' => $attributes['price'][$key],
        'quantity' => $attributes['quantity'][$key],
        'discount' => $attributes['discount'][$key]
    ]
}
if ($syncable) {
    $order->products()->sync($syncable);
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple products in my order, it does not work properly.It is removing all products and remains just the one modified.

Comment: @IonutPaduraru In your example of `$products` you provided only one ID. It is hard to see if it is a multi select field or simple from the image. Updated my answer

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5mYEcDf - I have those errors with your code, something is not ok it seems.

Comment: @IonutPaduraru try it like this then